# Groupby, map and sum in Pandas resulting in NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Data Multiple rows per ID

```
ID Value1 Value2
1    1     0
1    0     1
1    3     1
```

Desired output

For each ID, (SUM(Value1))*(Value2).

In this case it would be 4*0=0 for ID1.

I want the result to be placed back in the original table like below

```
ID Value1 Value2 Calculated_Value
1    1     0        0
1    0     1        4
1    3     1        4
```

I have tried this..it ran but I got NaN in the output table..

```
df['Calculated_Value'] = df['ID'].map(df.groupby('ID')['Value1'].sum()*['Value2'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` for this:

```
df['Calculated_Value'] = df.groupby('ID')['Value1'].transform('sum') * df['Value2']

print(df)

   ID  Value1  Value2  Calculated_Value
0   1       1       0                 0
1   1       0       1                 4
2   1       3       1                 4
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `.transform`:

```
df['Calculated_Value'] = df.groupby('ID').Value2. \
                            transform(lambda x: x * df['Value1'].sum())

print df

#    ID  Value1  Value2  Calculated_Value
# 0   1       1       0                 0
# 1   1       0       1                 4
# 2   1       3       1                 4
```

Answer (score 4):

We can using `groupby` and `mul`

```
df['Yourvalue']=df.set_index('ID').Value2.mul(df.groupby('ID').Value1.sum(),level=0).values
df
Out[278]: 
   ID  Value1  Value2  Yourvalue
0   1       1       0          0
1   1       0       1          4
2   1       3       1          4
```

Answer (score 2):

With `pd.factorize` and `np.bincount`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.ID)
df.assign(YourValue=np.bincount(f, df.Value1)[f] * df.Value2)

   ID  Value1  Value2  YourValue
0   1       1       0        0.0
1   1       0       1        4.0
2   1       3       1        4.0
```

---

Super sketchy use of `fillna` to automatically tell if I should downcast to `int`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(df.ID)
df.assign(YourValue=np.bincount(f, df.Value1)[f] * df.Value2).fillna(
    0, downcast='infer')

   ID  Value1  Value2  YourValue
0   1       1       0          0
1   1       0       1          4
2   1       3       1          4
```